# Build failed -- check your build output, deploying react app to heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, deployment

I was deploying my react application to heroku. My register page isnt working. When I push to heroku, it gives me no errors. When i say heroku logs --tail it gives me this. Attached are server.js file and heroku logs --tail output.

[image]

[image]

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please try to post code and relevant output using code formatting instead of screenshots. It will be easier for others to read, debug and reproduce.

Comment: The first image says.. build output failed. Have you checked the build log presented at the url. ?

Comment: @Panther             -----> Pruning devDependencies
       removed 117 packages and audited 1180 packages in 3.624s
      1 package is looking for funding
         run `npm fund` for details
       found 0 vulnerabilities
 Build succeeded!
Discovering process types
Procfile declares types-> (none)
Default types for buildpack -> web
Compressing...
Done: 50M
Launching...
 !Push failed due to an unrecognized error, and we've been notified.
 !Please try pushing again.
 !If the problem persists, see http://help.heroku.com/ and provide Request ID b01361df-e80a-7f93-6a4c-d3115d9e6594.

Comment: @Panther it says that at the url mentioned

Comment: Hmm.. Try to raise a request with heroku. It could an internal error as mentioned there. The push is failed.. so it means the deploy has failed.. The current running heroku app should be running from url last successful build. Also try running the app in same mode and same env variables as in heroku in ur local and see how it goes